# Forcing IFrame to open links in parent for an external site

Tags: html

How can I force an `IFrame` to open links inside the parent?

The only way I could find here on StackOverflow and over the net is to use the `target` attribute inside the links themselves or inside the `base` tag.

The problem starts when the source of the `IFrame` is external. For example, if I want to embbed Google inside the `IFrame`, I cannot alter the code of Google, so I need a way to tell the IFrame itself to open links in the parent, without touching the code of the source.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can not do that because of Same-origin security policy. read this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame